# AppleScript to download attachments from Mail.app

Tags: applescript, mail.app, email

I'm trying to create an Apple Script that triggers from a Mail Rule that will download attachments from a message to my Downloads folder. I found [this article](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91013/how-to-auto-download-a-certain-attachment-in-mail) from 2011 as a starting point.

I found the following script and changed the "Documents:Attachments" part on line 3 to "Downloads". I set up a Mail Rule that runs the script and adds a flag to the message as a way of knowing that the rule worked. During my test, the rule ran and the flag was added but the script didn't do anything:

```
    on perform_mail_action(ruleData)
   
    -- The folder to save the attachments in (must already exist)
    set attachmentsFolder to ((path to home folder as text) & "Documents:Attachments") as text

    -- Save in a sub-folder based on the name of the rule in Mail
    set subFolder to name of |Rule| of ruleData as text
    tell application "Finder"
       if not (exists folder subFolder of folder attachmentsFolder) then
           make new folder at attachmentsFolder with properties {name:subFolder}
       end if
   end tell

    -- Get incoming messages that match the rule
    tell application "Mail"
       set selectedMessages to |SelectedMessages| of ruleData
        repeat with theMessage in selectedMessages
           
            -- Get the date the message was sent
            set {year:y, month:m, day:d, hours:h, minutes:min} to theMessage's date sent
            set timeStamp to ("" & y & "-" & my pad(m as integer) & "-" & my pad(d) & "-" & my pad(h) & "-" & my pad(min))

            -- Save the attachment
            repeat with theAttachment in theMessage's mail attachments
               set originalName to name of theAttachment
                set savePath to attachmentsFolder & ":" & subFolder & ":" & timeStamp & " " & originalName
                try
                   save theAttachment in savePath
               end try
           end repeat
       end repeat
   end tell

end perform_mail_action

-- Adds leading zeros to date components
on pad(n)
   return text -2 thru -1 of ("00" & n)
end pad
```